What was blocking Thufir from guessing the Guild was bribed into forbidding satellites over Arrakis?
Soon after taking possession of Arrakis, the Atreides discover the Guild will not allow one of their frigates with a climate control system on board to orbit the planet.

The Guild agent [...] was merely making it plain --one Mentat to
another-- that the price was out of our reach and would remain so no
matter how long a reach we develop. Our task is to find out why before
we approach him again."

Later on, during a fit of oracular insight, Paul realizes that the Fremen bought this refusal from the Guild with a monstrous tribute in Spice.

Satellites watch the terrain below. [...] The Fremen! They're paying
the Guild for privacy, paying in a coin that's freely available to
anyone with desert power--spice. This is more than a
second-approximation answer; it's the straight-line computation.
Depend on it.

This is weird. In retrospect, there seems to be no need to bribe the Guild into forbidding satellites around the planet: water is poisonous to the sandworms, so rains would jeopardize the Spice cycle. More generally, the Guild does not want the ecology of Spice to become common lore because it opens the door to terrorist threats, of the precise kind that later triggered the Arrakis Affair. They would only allow Fremen (including the Kynes) to research it because they were addicted to it and could not spread their knowledge off-planet.
Of course Thufir does not know that: we the readers only collect this knowledge bit by bit in the course of the novel. Maybe it takes a near-KH to understand how much more precious the payment is to the Guild than to the general market. However, there is no want of people intent on keeping their juicy business on Arrakis private. The most obvious are the smugglers; if Piter De Vries knows Count Fenring to be "the Emperor's ambassador to the smugglers", Thufir should know it as well.
There is no want of good reasons for the Spice buyers to keep the extent of the smuggling secret, either: e. g. to conceal the available budget for a military venture being planned, like in the RL Iran-Contra affair. In-universe, any mentat would keep this in mind: IIRC, s/one observed in one later book, maybe Dune Messiah, that you can't hope for a victorious war if your enemy knows exactly how much budget you allocated to it.
What makes it unworthy, in Thufir's eyes, to mention the possibility the Guild is being bribed into not allowing satellites over Arrakis and the need to go find out by whom? What made the Kynes and the Fremen believe their secrets were threatened unless they paid the Guild to cover them?

That the sandworms produce spice is unknown to the wider world, hence it is non-obvious why the Guild opposes weather control or observation satellites.

@Valorum indeed it is not. However, 2things are known: they do not allow the Atreides to orbit a frigate around the planet and lucrative, clandestine business takes place on its surface. My point is, it is obvious they make more money by forbidding satellites than by allowing them and it is easy to conjecture it's money being paid to them. The real job is to guess who pays it and how much, not why they forbid satellites.

@FrançoisJurain - The guild is the only game in town. If you disobey them, you'll get stranded.

The Guild doesn't know where Spice comes from or how sandworms work either, and the Fremen want to keep it that way.

@OrangeDog according to the Appendices, the Guild are aware they may not take any concrete steps to control the availability of Spice. If this extends to knowing nothing about the ecology of Spice, surely they do not want any other political heavyweight any wiser than they are.

@OrangeDog I read Dune (specially the appendices) like the Fremen started bribing the Guild under Pardot Kynes. Back then, it was as risky as ever for the Guild themselves to start collecting intelligence about the Spice and surely, they did not want anyone else to do it. My question is: were they giving any sign they planned to deploy satellites? Given the risks, what was the point?

I don’t think the Fremen, until Paul, had any idea how dependent the Guild was on them. The Guild could only extort them because they didn’t know they could have simply threatened spice production for the same effect. Also, I dont think the Guild knew how spice worked, so unless they had oracular reasons for it they did not necessarily have a natural motivation to stop climate control.

@Shamshiel Indeed, I think this is the main point that this question is missing. There is a nice question with nice answers available on this site which provide in-text references to the main important point: Thufir is almost certainly unaware of the Guild's dependence on the Spice. Since the Guild is otherwise extremely wealthy (due to their high shipping fees), it'd seem unlikely that a mundane bribe was their motive. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/287559/at-the-start-of-dune-who-knew-about-the-spacing-guilds-dependence-on-spice

The question in the title of your post is simple enough.  The details and logic in the body of your post make things more complex.  I'll respond to the title and body separately below.
The Title's question:
This is my summary of the title's question:

In Chapter 22, Paul, who has training but little experience in being a Mentat, evaluates the evidence and computes the reason for the Guild's refusal to allow weather satellites over Arrakis: The Fremen are paying huge bribes to the Guild.  Paul says it's clearly true: "This is more than a second-approximation answer it's the straight-line computation."
Earlier, in Chapter 12, Thufir Hawat, a long-experienced Mentat, does not seem able to make the same computation as Paul does to reach the same conclusion.

What information/data was Hawat missing that prevented him from reaching the same answer as Paul?
Answer:
The answer is given in the same scene where Paul makes the computation and describes it to Jessica (Chapter 12):

Paul lifted the seal on the pack, pulled out a tiny micromanual with glowtab and magnifier.  Freen and orange letters leaped up at him from the pages: "literjons, stilltent, energy caps, recaths, sandsnork, binoculars, stillsuit repkit, baradye pistol, sinkchart, filt-plugs, paracompass, maker hooks, thumpers, Fremkit, Fire pillar..."  So many things for survival on the desert.
[...]
"We've all the evidence in our hands," he said. "Right here in this tent -- the tent itself, this pack and its contents, these stillsuits."

Hawat knew there were many more Fremen than the Harkonnens and the Emperor thought, and he knew how well the Fremen could fight.  But these didn't add up to the Fremen having motivation or means to pay large bribes to the Guild.
The puzzle piece that Hawat lacked was firsthand evidence of how sophisticated the Fremen technology and economy were.  The Fremen were thriving rather than barely clinging to survival, and this allowed them to complete the computation for Paul where there was a gap for Hawat.
As for motivation, Chapter 22 doesn't describe how this would have fit into Paul's computation.  I myself have always felt that Paul's meeting with Kynes and his honor guard (the day they rescued workers from the worm that swallowed the spice harvester) and Kynes' transfixed reaction to Jessica at the dinner party when she described a dream that water and green plants would someday exist on Arrakis, were part of Paul's awareness during the computation.  Thus Paul could see that through Kynes, the Fremen had motive to hide the changes already happening on the planet's surface; and the tent, pack, and Fremkit in his hands showed Paul the Fremen were capable of harvesting spice themselves.  But that's my interpretation, not directly supported by the text of Chapter 22.

The Body of the post:
You said:

In retrospect, there seems to be no need to bribe the Guild into forbidding satellites around the planet: water is poisonous to the sandworms, so rains would jeopardize the Spice cycle.

The Fremen weren't hiding rains, though.  In Chapter 32 Jessica and Paul have traveled with Stilgar's party to the Cave of the Ridges before reaching Sietch Tabr.  Shortly before Jamis challenges Paul to fight, Jessica and Stilgar have a conversation where Stilgar tells Jessica about the spice bribes:

"It's Liet's command," Stilgar said. "We know the reason, but the taste of it sours us.  We bribe the Guild to keep our skies clear of satellites and such that none may spy what we do to the face of Arrakis."
[...] "And what is it you do to the face of Arrakis that must not be seen?"
"We change it...slowly but with certainty...to make it fit for human life.  Our generation will not see it, nor our children nor our children's children nor the grandchildren of their children...but it will come."  He stared with veiled eyes out over the basin.  "Open water and tall green plants and people walking freely without stillsuits."

The Fremen were still at an early stage of the plan to change Arrakis, long before any rains. Appendix I of the book describes stages in the plan.  In the beginning they introduce grasses and plants to stabilize dunes:

Downwind sides of old dunes provided the first plantation areas.  The Fremen aimed first for a cycle of poverty grass with peat-like hair cilia to intertwine, mat and fix the dunes by depriving the wind of its big weapon: moveable grains.
Adaptive zones were laid out in the deep south far from Harkonnen watchers. The mutated poverty grasses were planted first along the downwind (slipface) of the chosen dunes that stood across the path of the prevailing westerlies.  With the downwind face anchored, the windward face grew higher and higher and the grass was moved to keep pace.  Giant sifs (long dunes with sinuous crests) of more than 1,500 meters height were produced this way.

These zones of grasses and their growing dunes were the things that the Fremen were hiding with their bribe.  The appendix indicates that the elder Kynes estimated 350 years to complete the plan, and judging by the age of Liet-Kynes at his father's death (19) and his age in the book (40s-50s) this estimate was made 2-3 decades before the Atreides arrived. The plan still had generations to run before rain would appear.
TL;DR:
Paul had data from the survival gear to show the Fremen were organized and sophisticated enough to bribe the Guild.  He may also have perceived the leadership Kynes had with the Fremen and the dream they had to change the planet.  Hawat would have eventually developed these facts through Duncan Idaho's alliance with the Fremen and his other spies, and then he would have been able to find the same answer as Paul, but the Harkonnen and Imperial betrayal arrived too soon.

Right on, +1, mentats are computers and function on the data they have.  Limit the input, limit the output, plus GIGO.  P. Kynes and the Fremen limited the input.  We the readers have more information than any one character.

I think the answer is so trivial that it was not worth mentioning by Thufir Hawat.  The Fremen are hiding from the Harkonnens.  The sietches have moisture traps and greenery that could be spotted from orbit and there are a lot more of them than the Harkonnens think.  The Fremen have access to large amounts of spice.
The conclusion is that the Fremen bribe the spacing guild so they can not be spied on from orbit.  This is a conclusion that is not worth mentioning.  Since the Atreides strategy is to ally with the Fremen there is no need to try to figure out a way to get around this.  Another reason not to bother mentioning it.
Unfortunately I can't find actual quotes (and if anyone wants to do so I'll happily delete this answer in favour of a better one) but in the second or third book there are multiple mentions of sietches in the deep desert that are safe because thopters never go there.  There is also an encounter with smugglers who have travelled too deep in to the desert and seen too much and therefore must die.  I remember this as definitely being about the hidden sietches, greenery and secret water supplies not about the sandworm life cycle.

Sorry, I fail to see any connection with my question. There is no doubt observation satellites would be damaging to the Fremen; the weird thing is, the bribe did apparently not aim at having extant satellites removed or to counter an ongoing plan to deploy new ones. On the contrary, the Guild had already every incentive to reject such plans, for motives of their own. What was the point of approaching the Guild & offer to pay for privacy? It would only signal to them s/th fishy was going on, not add any measure of safety.

@FrançoisJurain - I think the problem is that your question is over-wordy and under-clear

@Valorum This is quite possible. How do you understand the 2 sentences in bold, at the end of the post? I could change that for starters.

@FrançoisJurain - I'd normally be all over a Dune question but I'm struggling to understand your main thesis. It seems to boil down to "Why did the Guild need to be bribed to do something they were already doing?" but I can't be sure that's what you're driving at

Yes it is, about 50% of it. The other half is "Why would Thufir not even conjecture the Guild was getting regular bribes, even if it was too difficult to guess from whom? He knew Spice smugglers with big customers were an actual thing". Thanks for the feedback. I'll rephrase my post.

@FrançoisJurain the problem is there is no basis for your assertion that the Guild already wanted to prevent all satellites themselves.
